# How to check if Drupal modules are up to date ?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, drupal-7

I am using a monitoring tool (Sensu) to execute multiple checks to know if a server has problems.

I have already written a ruby script to know if a wordpress is up to date, to do that I connect through a ssh tunnel to the server, and I connect to his wordpress database, and then I check a table where I parse some data. For exemple if response=lastest, the core is up to date.

I want to do the same for Drupal, but I can't find useful data in the drupal database which says me that a module or the core is up to date, I only the find version number in system table.

Have you got an idea how can I check if drupal modules are up to date, if possible from an another server than the one where drupal is installed ?

Thanks.

Comment: use reports section to check if your site is up to date or not. Navigate to url http://{your_domain}/admin/reports/updates section to check if update report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module called nagios (https://www.drupal.org/project/nagios) that will allow you to visit a "check page" and it will check the status of a number of different things that you can monitor.

I would only caution if you are using a Drupal Distribution, not all the modules get updated in a timely fashion, but if you are using the standard Drupal installation you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is one nagios plugin I found which does not require any modules to be installed into drupal. However, it requires drush (http://www.drush.org) on the server which holds the drupal site:

https://github.com/cytopia/check_drupal